# Product of operators

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A:l_{p}\rightarrow l_{p},A\left( x_{1},x_{2},\ldots \right) =\left(
0,x_{1},x_{2},\ldots \right) $ and $B:l_{p}\rightarrow l_{p},A\left(
x_{1},x_{2},\ldots \right) =\left( x_{1},x_{2}/2,x_{3}/3,\ldots \right) $.
Then $U=AB=\left( 0,x_{1},x_{2}/2,x_{3}/3,\ldots \right) $.

Can someone explain how to get the operator U step by step. I know that this is a product of operators, but do not know how to multiply operators. Thanks.

Comment: It's just composition. Don't you know how to compose functions? If $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x-23$ then can you calculate $f\circ g(x)=f(g(x))$?

Comment: I know the composition functions: f∘g(x)=f(g(x))=f(x−23)=(x-23)^2

Comment: But still I do not see, why in the first place is 0, in the second X1,third X2/2, etc.

Comment: In the first place, there is a $0$, because the result of $A$ always has a $0$ on the first axis. On the second one, you have $x_1$, because the result of $A$ always has on the second axis what it received on the first, and $B$ keeps it unchanged. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

This is a composition of two operator .I think you know how to compute composition of two function .Still i show it below . 
  $AB(x_1,x_2, x_3, \cdots \cdots)$
  $=A(x_1 ,\frac{x_2}{2},\frac{x_3}{3},\cdot \cdots) $
  $=(0 ,x_1 ,\frac{x_2}{2},\frac{x_3}{3},\cdot \cdots)$

Comment: I know that, but this part A(x1,x2/2,x3/3,...) =(0,x1,x2/2,x3/3,...) I do not understand